# How can I run a cable past a horizontal block between studs in my wall?

Tags: television

I am in the middle of hiding my flatscreen cables within my bedroom wall to hide. I'm done drilling the holes and I am trying to fish the cable through, but there is a horizontal block of somesort that is preventing my efforts. What is this and what is my recourse?

Answer (score 5):

You need a [long, flexible auger bit](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Southwire-3-4-in-Flex-Auger-Bit/1000056709). I have this model and found it invaluable when I need to add a new cable inside the wall. The kit has a 90 degree handle that fits on the shaft and lets you bend it to fit through the wall opening to reach the bottom or top of the stud bay and drill through. This [forum page](https://www.doityourself.com/forum/electrical-ac-dc/553209-how-fish-cable-inside-exterior-wall.html) gives a nice rundown and pictures of the bit in use.

There's a eyelet in the bit where you can fasten a cable to pull back through the hole you drilled, too.

The mid-bay 2x4 is a brace. Some walls have them, some don't. I don't know whether that's a builder's decision or building code. None of my walls have them.

Comment: In some areas, building codes require diagonal bracing let into the studs at the corners of the walls. It's entirely possible that this is what you're running into. If so, this answer is still applicable, but it may be a bit harder to get the auger to bite into the angled board - just keep working at it, or possibly try tipping the bit to get it at a right-angle to the (possibly) diagonal bracing.

Comment: @FreeMan, yes, it is possible to hit a diagonal brace with some effort. In my situation, I was only going through retro-fitted fire-blocking at the top/bottom of the stud bay (balloon framing).

Answer (score 3):

Some choices:

- Cut the drywall above or below the horizontal and drill a hole through it.
- Get a long reach spade or auger bit and drill a hole from the existing hole in your drywall.